Images in a flexbox don't resize if I make them links
I have a flexbox of three square images, which I want to adjust to the size of the browser window as I narrow or widen it. I've managed to do this. However, I would like each image to be a link. When I try to do this, the images don't grow or shrink anymore.
This is the code where the images are not links, and the pictures resize as I want them to:
HTML:
<div class="container">

  <img src="001.jpg">
  <img src="002.jpg">
  <img src="003.jpg">

</div>


CSS:
.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container img {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 1 400px
}

I've tried for instance:
<a href="website.html"><img src="001.jpg"></a>

And change the second part of the CSS to
.container a

instead of
.container img

But this, or other solutions that I've tried don't work, as the images don't grow or shrink when I change the window size.

So you links should be flex:1 and the images width:100%.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Set image width as 100% so they cover entire width of the anchor element, then it will work as expected


.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container a {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 1 1 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200"></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/200"></a>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/200"></a>
</div>



